# How to use Jupyter Notebook to highlight the code(in code cell)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Newbie to Jupyter notebook, I know how to use markdown or html grammar to highlight code in "markdown cell", but don't know how to highlight in "code cell".

Examples are shown in below pictures.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mexnw.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NH7V.jpg)

Comment: Got the answer from another perspective(reason: indent of code): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/dnGLSC49FyY

Answer (score 0):

In a markdown cell, you can surround the code with three backticks and the name of the programming language

````
```python
for x in my_list:
    print(x)
```
````

In a code cell, the code will be highlighted automatically. If you want to customise the code highlighting of the notebook maybe this plugin will help. [Jupyter themes](https://github.com/merqurio/jupyter_themes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, and I have got an answer another perspective: The indent of our code will affect the parsing result of CodeMirror, so the red parts will be treated like "mistake".